# Running Xorg won't detect mouse in SUM

Tags: shell, linux-kernel, xorg

So I've been sort of experimenting with the linux kernel lately (with the end goal of making my own distro), and added `rw init=/bin/sh` to my boot params, to enter this extremely light Single User Mode. I wanted to see if Xorg would work, so I did

```bsh
xinit /bin/fvwm
```

as an experiment. As expected, the FVWM screen came up, but my mouse wouldn't work. It works fine in multi user mode.

My question is just this: What is the difference between the two modes that prevents my mouse from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your udev-rules are not applied, so your peripherals (and probably much more) are not detected/initialized.

If you want to learn, how to make your own distribution or learning Linux in depth, I can recommend [Linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) or [gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/) first. LFS is targeted at people who want to learn more on linux-basics while gentoo is in fact a distribution-construction-kit (or a very very time-consumpting single-user distibution)